# Docker: Run image created from script in detached mode, in interactive mode

Tags: docker

I have prepared an image by running a container in detached mode with

```
docker run -itd <image-name> sh run.sh
```

Where run.sh was a script placed inside the container. When the script was done the container stopped, and i saved it as a new image with

```
docker commit <container-id> <new-image-name>
```

**Now I want run commands inside containers created from the new image with something like**

```
docker run -it <new-image-name>
```

**but when I try this, it automatically starts the same script as before, and I dont enter the container in interactive mode as I expected. What have I done wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a new image from your own Dockerfile.
You can do that using FROM <source_img> with a COPY of your script and then running that script inside your build using RUN. After that you could create a custom ENTRYPOINT with commands to run on your container startup.

You could also run your container in interactive mode by giving it a command.
For example if your base image was nginx you could run your new image like this:

```
docker run -it <new-image-name> bash
```

If your image base uses a different linux distribution you would have to run it giving the container a different command to run e.g. "sh".

If you're still having issues you could also try changing the entry point of your image using

> --entrypoint

It would be much easier to help with more details on your use case and what's the base image you're using.